# Find the flux of a charge through a finite plane

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

I'm having struggle with the following problem:

**Find the flux due to a charge P located on the z-axis on a squared plane on the xOy plane. P=(0,0,d) and the plane goes from (0,0,0) to (d,d,0)**

I've tried to integrate over the surface but it becomes too complicated. How would you approach this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: The integral is quite doable; you get an integral of the form $\int_0^d d\sigma_1 \int_0^d d\sigma_2 \, (\sigma^2_1 + \sigma^2_2 + d^2)^{-3/2}$, and with all the constants thrown in you will get the same answer as the symmetry argument, $q/24\epsilon_0$.

Comment: How do you get past the second integration? The first one is simple since two of the terms inside the brackets are treated as constants and it is a known integral. But for the second integration, the denominator changes and becomes the product of two different terms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the whole cube $D$ of side $l = 2d$, centered in $P$. The vertices of the cube $D$ will be $V_1(0,d,d),\  V_2(0,d,-d),\  V_3(0,-d,d),\  V_4(0,-d,-d),\ V_5(2d,d,d),\ V_6 (2d,d,-d),\ V_7 (2d,-d,d),\ V_8 (2d,-d,-d)  $.

Then by Gauss' Theorem

$$
\Phi_D(\vec E) = \frac q{\epsilon_0}.
$$

By simmetry, each and every face is divided into quarters just like the bottom one: since $D$ has six faces, and you integrate on a quarter of one, your answer is
$$
\Phi(\vec E) = \frac q{24\epsilon_0}.
$$